# Any way to read Serilog's LogContext later in a downstream class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm pushing values to the Serilog `LogContext` in a middleware class of a .NET Core web app:-

```
using LogContext.PushProperty("MyAct", "some clever joke") ...
```

Is it possible to read the value for `MyAct` property in a downstream class?  I don't see anything promising on the LogContext class - seems like a write only entity, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: What is downstream class here ? Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serilog does not provide for you to Just Read the values from the `LogContext`.

Normally the `PushProperty` stashes it, and `Enrich.FromLogContext` is charged with grabbing the contextual information that will accompany the destructured message and tokens as the logging call is *capturing* them into the `LogEvent` that'll then be passed to the chain of *sinks*.

Really this begs the question: [why do you feel you need to do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

---

Actually answering the question: It is possible the underlying APIs are exposed in a usable fashion though; I'd go to https://github.com/serilog/serilog - the `LogContext` impl and tests are all in that core repo.

Comment: `Why do you feel you need to do this` - in a middleware component, I add the Referrer for the web request to the LogContext.  I need the Referrer down the line (Controller->Business->Repository->HelperClass) to do some calculations.  So rather than pass the Referrer all the way through the class structure, I thought I'll cheat and just grab it from LogContext.

Comment: Ha - this is probably a hack too far in that case. I'd suggest looking at the impl technique and stealing _that_ instead ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. I want to write a Unit test for my Middleware that pushes context and want to test if I am pushing the right context information.

I solved it by creating a Logger that writes to an observer.
(Adding the Serilog.Sinks.Observable to my test dependencies)

```
private class LogEventStoreObserver : IObserver<LogEvent>
{
   public LogEvent LastEvent { get; set; }
   public void OnCompleted() { }
   public void OnError(Exception error) { }
   public void OnNext(LogEvent value) 
   {
       LastEvent = value;
    }
}

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Observers(events =>
                 events.Subscribe(logObserver))
                       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                       .CreateLogger();
```

Now I can read the LogEvent properties which contains the LogContext like this:

```
// Setup
LogEvent testLogEvent = null;
nextMock.Setup(_ => _(It.IsAny<HttpContext>())).Callback<HttpContext>((_) =>
    {
        Log.Information("Test");
        testLogEvent = logObserver.LastEvent;
    });

// Act
await middleware.InvokeAsync(httpContext);

// Verify
testLogEvent.Properties.Should().ContainKey("mySpecialContext");
```